# Dumpcap - Ram still reserved after stop

Tags: windows, wireshark

System: Win 10 Pro and latest updates (Sept. 2020) 64Bit.

Problem: Using dumpcap (Dumpcap (Wireshark) 3.2.5 (v3.2.5-0-ged20ddea8138)) with a ringbuffer reserves RAM even after closing the dumpcap.exe. The PC needs to be restarted to free the mem. Login off doesn't do it.

Dumpcap command:

Exe: C:\Program Files\Wireshark\dumpcap.exe

Arguments:  -i "Interface" -w "ValidLogFolder" -b files:20 -b filesize:600

Filesize does not really mather, even with a 2GByte Filesize i get the same behaviour. I chekced if i have files * filesize * [KByte] ram free. The data is saved on a ssd.

Before starting the dumpcap.exe the RAM usage is around 4GByte. When i let it run (10Gbit Interface with 8Gbit/s traffic) the usage crawls up. In the following picture is the RAM usage after i stopped the dumpcap.exe. The usage stays where i stop the dumpcap.

[image]

Also, the ringbuffer is not overwriting existing files, its adding new files. I Tried canging the order of the commands.

What is going on here?

I want to make a ringbuffer to make a long term monitoring of the massive traffic.

Edit:
I opened an issue on Gitlab:
https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues/16846

Comment: Search the Gitlab issues for a similar problem, and if you can't find one create one for this. https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues?label_name%5B%5D=cli%3A%3Adumpcap

Comment: Have you tried to restart the pcap service that does the actual traffic sniffing?

Comment: I'll look through the Gitlab and update the question.
@Robert I haven't found dumpcap/wireshark in the processes list in the task manager and found no service called wireshark, dumpcap or pcap after creating the problem. Should it have another name? I looked through the running services and couldn't find one which sounds like  it has an association with dumpcap.

Comment: @Eggi npcap ist installed as drive hence it is not visible in the services list. However you can restart it via admin PowerShell: `Restart-Service npcap`.

Comment: @Robert Restart-Service npcap and Stop-Service npcap didn't free the memory.

Comment: Ok to those downvoting this question:
Can you at least tell me what I can improve for future questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the npcap driver 0.9994. To quote the answer from GitLAB:

> Yes previous versions of Npcap were leaking memory. They are hopefully
> fixed with 0.9997... We currently ship Npap 0.9997 in our Wireshark
> 3.3.0 development snapshots and we will bundle it in Wireshark 3.2.7.